# Have problems with installing AR foundation and ar core in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Have these Many problems with Unity and need help with them

[image]

**Errors:**

```
1-Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.arcore@2.1.2\Runtime\ARCoreImageTrackingProvider.cs(35,60): error CS1715: 'ARCoreImageTrackingProvider.Provider.imageLibrary': type must be 'RuntimeReferenceImageLibrary' to match overridden member 'XRImageTrackingSubsystem.IProvider.imageLibrary'
2-Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.arcore@2.1.2\Runtime\ARCoreImageTrackingProvider.cs(33,15): error CS0534: 'ARCoreImageTrackingProvider.Provider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'XRImageTrackingSubsystem.IProvider.imageLibrary.set'
3-Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.arcore@2.1.2\Runtime\ARCoreImageTrackingProvider.cs(33,15): error CS0534: 'ARCoreImageTrackingProvider.Provider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'XRImageTrackingSubsystem.IProvider.CreateRuntimeLibrary(XRReferenceImageLibrary)'
4-Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
5-Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
6-UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:191 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Unity version: **2018.3.14f1**

Answer (score 2):

Hey man i figured it out. You must use the correct versioon of the package for each 2018 and 2019 unity. see the  below::  [follow my linkedin XR-Company page for more XR support :](https://www.linkedin.com/company/xr-i/?viewAsMember=true)

For Unity 2018:

- AR Foundation 1.0.0 — preview.22 (the latest for 1.0.0)
- ARCore XR Plugin 1.0.0 — preview.24 (the latest for 1.0.0)
- ARKit XR Plugin 1.0.0-preview.27 (the latest for 1.0.0)

For Unity 2019:

- AR Foundation 2.0.2
- ARCore XR Plugin 2.0.2
- ARKit XR Plugin 2.0.2

Answer (score 1):

if you are using unity 2018.3.x (as you mentioned in your Question)

1- AR Foundation 1.0.0 — preview.22 (the latest for 1.0.0) don't
   import 2.x.

2 - ARCore XR Plugin 1.0.0 — preview.24 (the latest for 1.0.0)

3- ARKit XR Plugin 1.0.0-preview.27 (the latest for 1.0.0)

second thing is that if you check the change the log then you will find that which version is compatible with which one

Answer (score 1):

Just do 2 things check your Unity version in top Left corner and if it is **2018** install latest version from `1.0.0` of

1. AR Foundation
2. ARCore XR Plugin
3. List item

And if you have **2019** version  install latest version from `2.0.0` of

1. AR Foundation
2. ARCore XR Plugin
3. List item

from **`Window->Package Manager`** and If you are not able to find this package go to
**`Window->Package Manager->Advanced and check on Show preview packges`**
And if you have already installed another version remove that and install this version

Answer (score 0):

**This is due to incompatible version of the packages.** We know that each Unity 3D supporting only few list of versions and it is not backward compatible too. means if you are trying to open a project in Unity 3D 2018 version but it is actually developed on Unity 3D 2019 then definitely you will get some sort of package issues in your console.

The following are the packages with versions which is compatible in specific version of Unity.

**For Unity 2018:**

- AR Foundation 1.0.0 — preview.22 (the latest for 1.0.0)
- ARCore XR Plugin 1.0.0 — preview.24 (the latest for 1.0.0)
- ARKit XR Plugin 1.0.0-preview.27 (the latest for 1.0.0)

**For Unity 2019:**

- AR Foundation 2.0.2
- ARCore XR Plugin 2.0.2
- ARKit XR Plugin 2.0.2

You can add those packages from Package Manager. You can get it from `Window --> Package Manager` in Unity 2018.3 + versions. If you are trying to use this packages in Unity which version is less than 2018.3 then add those in your `manifest.json` file located under Packages folder.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "com.unity.xr.arcore": "1.0.0-preview.24",
    "com.unity.xr.arfoundation": "1.0.0-preview.22",
    "com.unity.xr.arkit": "1.0.0-preview.27"
  }
}
```